# Detect single values surrounded by NaN/NA pattern

Tags: r

I am looking for a pattern to detect values that are surrounded by NAs or NaNs.

My data looks like this:

```
c(1,2,3,NA,NaN,NA,6,9,10,NaN,NA,12,20,NA,NaN,12,NA,45,100,NA,200,NA,NaN,300)
```

I need to know all **single** trapped values that are either between NA or NaN.

The result from the above example would be: `c(12, 200)`

Any elegant ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `lag` and `lead` function from `dplyr` you can do -

```
library(dplyr)

x[!is.na(x) & is.na(lag(x, default = 1)) & is.na(lead(x, default = 1))]
#[1]  12 200
```

This basically returns a non-NA value trapped between `NA` values.

Comment: Neat and short! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace all `NA` with `X`
2. collapse to vector with one string element
3. use `str_extract` with regex:

```
library(stringr)

#data
vector <- c(1,2,3,NA,NaN,NA,6,9,10,NaN,NA,12,20,NA,NaN,12,NA,45,100,NA,200,NA,NaN,300)

vector[is.na(vector)] <- "X"
vector1 <- paste(vector,collapse=" ")
unlist(str_extract_all(vector1, "(?<=X )\\d+(?= X)"))
```

Output:

```
[1] "12"  "200"
```

Comment: "Base R", yet you load `stringr`  — thanks anyway!

Comment: ups ...... was the rest of my first try. ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can use `shift` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
x[!is.na(x) & is.na(shift(x, fill = 1)) & is.na(shift(x, type = 'lead', fill = 1))]
```

-ouptut

```
[1]  12 200
```